# tengo problemas con el audio de mi pagina en html y js

Tags: javascript, html, html5

buenas tardes tengo problemas con el audio en html le puse autoplay a la etiqueta audio pero cuando recargo no se reproduce nuevamente, no arroja ningun error y el audio lo tengo en dos formatos diferentes, navegador chrome y el audio pesa masomenos 4.5 mb

este es mi html:

```
<body>
    <audio autoplay loop id="bg-musica">
        <source src="/media/audio/quazar-city.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        <source src="/media/audio/quazar-city.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Sonido</legend> 
            <label for="">Musica</label>
            <input type="range" name="" id="barra-volumen" min="0" max="1" step="0.1">
            <label for="mute">Mute <input  type="checkbox" name="mute" id="mute"></label>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

este es mi js

```
//volume control
const $musica = document.getElementById("bg-musica");
const $barra = document.querySelector('#barra-volumen')

$barra.addEventListener("change",function(ev){  
    $musica.volume = ev.currentTarget.value;    
  },true);

//muted and unmuted (opciones)
 const $mute = document.querySelector('#mute')
 $mute.addEventListener("change", mutePlay, false);
 
 function mutePlay() {
    let checked = $mute.checked;
   if(checked){
    $musica.volume = 0;
   }else {
    $musica.volume = 1;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Chrome y los navegadores basados en él, el autoplay no funciona cuando existe sonido. Esto es igual para los elementos  y . Solo es posible la reproducción automática cuando existe el atributo "muted", ejemplo

```
<audio src=".." autoplay muted >
```

Más información: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Antes existían algunos trucos para sortear esto, se usaba un iframe o un archivo de sonido en silencio. Estos trucos ya no funcionan, y hasta donde mi conocimiento alcanza, a la fecha no existe un truco para sortear esto.

Cabe aclarar que el sonido se puede activar por javascript, solo luego de que el usuario haya tenido al menos una interactividad con la página

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias si lo suponía por eso puse una primera pantalla y luego del apretar un boton recien se entraba a la pagina y asi funciona sin problemas